# Drupal 7 update.php Notice: Array to string conversion in update_results_page() when running custom module update

Tags: 7

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in update_results_page() (line 212 of /Users/timdaff/Sites/local-quest-skills-for-life/update.php).
```

I'm getting the above notice after running update.php on the update function for my module.  It is a simple update to disable some modules I no longer require.  I'm not a PHP guru and it appears to me I have everything correct.

```
/**
 * Disabling modules. Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function features_controller_update_6009() {
    $return = array();
    $modules = array('views_cache_bully');
    $modules[] = 'gauth';
    $modules[] = 'oauth_common';
    $modules[] = 'oauth2_common';
    module_disable($modules,TRUE);
    $return[] = array('success' => TRUE, 'query' => 'Disabling views_cache_bully, oauth, gauth, gauth_login');
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7), the return value should be a string (the message to show to the user after the update) or null.

Currently you're returning an array, hence the notice.

Answer (score 1):

The return value you are using is the value `hook_update_N()` would return in Drupal 6. In fact, in Drupal 6 it was common to use code similar to the following one. (See [`locale_update_6000()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21locale%21locale.install/function/locale_update_6000/6).)

```
$ret[] = update_sql("DROP TABLE {locales_meta}");
```

That is the only case where Drupal code actually populate the `$ret` value; in the other cases, it just returns an empty array.

```
function comment_update_6003() {
  $ret = array();
  db_add_index($ret, 'comments', 'pid', array('pid'));
  return $ret;
}
```

Drupal 7 is especting a string to be returned, or `NULL`; Drupal core code usually doesn't return a string. An exception is supposed to be raised in case of fatal errors.

```
function aggregator_update_7002() {
  db_add_field('aggregator_feed', 'queued', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'description' => 'Time when this feed was queued for refresh, 0 if not queued.',
  ));
  db_add_index('aggregator_feed', 'queued', array('queued'));
}
```

Keep in mind that Drupal 7 takes the update description from the comment placed on top of the hook itself; in most of the cases, that is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm just returning a string now successfully.  Yes I had found the comment above to be used, and now don't really see the point in returning a string if you can't specify whether it's a success message or an error.  Why not just use the comment above entirely.